# Symfony 2.8 - Assign YAML variable under sentance variable

Tags: symfony, yaml

I have a YAML variable like this

```
test: 'Hello jack, please update your profile'
```

I want to make the name on another variable, and assign it under the sentance

```
test: 'Hello %name%, please update your profile'
name: 'jack'
```

But this solution, it doesn't work, Is there any solution?

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? Do you get an error or is the variable not recognized? Are you using this inside Symfony configuration, translations or some other custom use case?

Comment: What does your instructor say?  Usually there is some option to get help with classroom assignments.

Comment: @dbrumann, yes I use it on translation, the message show like this `Hello %name%, please update your profile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Symfony translation component allows for ['message placeholders'](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html#message-placeholders)

The yaml file:

```
# translations/app.en.yaml ('app' is the 'message domain')
say_hello: 'Hello {name}, please update your profile'
```

from PHP

```
// prints "Hello ....!"
echo $translator->trans('say_hello', ['name' => 'Sayou']);
```

Using [Twig Templates](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/templates.html#using-twig-tags):

```
{% trans with {'%name%': 'Sayou'} from 'app' %}say_hello{% endtrans %}
```

The output, from Twig:

> Hello Sayou, please update your profile